# How can I make different constructors for different temperature units in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, temperature

So you should be able to input temperature in C, K or F, which will call a different constructor for each of them. How do those constructors differ?

Comment: Any code to look at? What have you done so far? Have you defined different classes?

Comment: Different constructor of what class? Could you please show at least a hint of what you have in mind?

Comment: I'm not allowed to define different classes. I have no idea how can I make three different constructors for different units. I only know how to make constructors that will differ by input type(int, double,...).

Comment: So I should have three different constructors for C, K and F degrees. Then, when I input e.g. F letter and then the number, it should call a constructor for Fahrenheit to create an object.

Comment: Your design seems odd. Either declare a base class and derive classes or use something like strings to identify the Units.

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Different code for different units?  This should be data driven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the dedicated datatypes for the **value** of temperature, like:

```
struct Celsius { double value; }
struct Kelvin  { double value; }
struct Farahemsomething { double value; }
```

then you can just use simple overloads:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Celsius temp) {   .... = temp.value; ... }
    MyClass(Kelvin temp) {   .... = temp.value; ... }
    ...
}
```

However, if you everywhere use just `double` for all values, then you will have to differentiate the constructors with **something else**. Enums may be quite useful, but you will have it in the same constructor and have to switch over the enum value:

```
enum TemperatureUnits
{ Celsius,Kelvin, Farahemsomething };

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(TemperatureUnits unit, double value) {
        if(unit == Celsius)
        { ... }
        else if(unit == ....
           ...
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also mix "hollow types" with raw double to artificially enable the use of overloads, but it gets tricky:

```
struct Celsius { }
struct Kelvin  { }
struct Farahemsomething { }

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Celsius unit, double value) {   .... = value; ... }
    MyClass(Kelvin unit, double value) {   .... = value; ... }
    ...
}
```

Here, note that "unit" is just an empty struct that allows you to pick correct overload, so you invoke the constructor with simple empty "Celsius" followed by 234.55 value.

EDIT: and yet again I forgot about C11 features.. AnotherTest's suggestion about custom literals is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using C++11, you could use user-defined literals to express that a number is in Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celcius.

If you're not using C++11, you can always have an enum type parameter to your constructor that expresses this. The user-defined literal approach is probably much better though.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late with this, but here is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream> 

namespace units {
    template<int> struct temp_unit { };
    typedef temp_unit<1> celcius;
    typedef temp_unit<2> fahrenheit;
    typedef temp_unit<3> kelvin;
    typedef temp_unit<4> reaumur;
    typedef temp_unit<5> rankine;
}

namespace priv {
    struct converter_impl {
        virtual ~converter_impl() { }

        virtual float to_celcius() const = 0;
        virtual float to_fahrenheit() const = 0;
        virtual float to_kelvin() const = 0;
        virtual float to_reaumur() const = 0;
        virtual float to_rankine() const = 0;
    };

    struct from_celcius : converter_impl {
    protected:
        float m_value;
    public:
        from_celcius(float v) : m_value(v) { }

        float to_celcius() const { return m_value; }
        float to_fahrenheit() const { return (m_value * 1.8) + 32; }
        float to_kelvin() const { return (m_value + 273.15); }
        float to_reaumur() const { return (m_value * 0.8); }
        float to_rankine() const { return (m_value * 1.8 +32 + 459.67); }
    };

    struct from_fahrenheit : converter_impl {
    protected:
        float m_value;
    public:
        from_fahrenheit(float v) : m_value(v) { }

        float to_celcius() const { return ((m_value - 32) / 1.8); }
        float to_fahrenheit() const { return m_value; }
        float to_kelvin() const { return ((m_value + 459.67) / 1.8); }
        float to_reaumur() const { return ((m_value - 32) / 2.25); }
        float to_rankine() const { return (m_value + 459.67); }
    };

    struct from_kelvin : converter_impl {
    protected:
        float m_value;
    public:
        from_kelvin(float v) : m_value(v) { }

        float to_celcius() const { return (m_value - 273.15); }
        float to_fahrenheit() const { return ((m_value * 1.8) - 459.67); }
        float to_kelvin() const { return m_value; }
        float to_reaumur() const { return ((m_value - 273.15) * 0.8); }
        float to_rankine() const { return (m_value * 1.8); }
    };

    struct from_reaumur : converter_impl {
    protected:
        float m_value;
    public:
        from_reaumur(float v) : m_value(v) { }

        float to_celcius() const { return (m_value * 1.25); }
        float to_fahrenheit() const { return ((m_value * 2.25) + 32); }
        float to_kelvin() const { return ((m_value * 1.25) + 273.15); }
        float to_reaumur() const { return m_value; }
        float to_rankine() const { return ((m_value * 2.25) + 32 + 459.67); }
    };

    struct from_rankine : converter_impl {
    protected:
        float m_value;
    public:
        from_rankine(float v) : m_value(v) { }

        float to_celcius() const { return ((m_value - 32 - 459.67) / 1.8); }
        float to_fahrenheit() const { return (m_value  - 459.67); }
        float to_kelvin() const { return (m_value / 1.8); }
        float to_reaumur() const { return ((m_value - 32 - 459.67) / 2.25); }
        float to_rankine() const { return m_value; }
    };
}

struct temp_converter {
protected:
    priv::converter_impl * m_impl;
public:
    temp_converter(float value, units::celcius)     : m_impl(new priv::from_celcius(value)) { }
    temp_converter(float value, units::fahrenheit)  : m_impl(new priv::from_fahrenheit(value)) { }
    temp_converter(float value, units::kelvin)      : m_impl(new priv::from_kelvin(value)) { }
    temp_converter(float value, units::reaumur)     : m_impl(new priv::from_reaumur(value)) { }
    temp_converter(float value, units::rankine)     : m_impl(new priv::from_rankine(value)) { }
    ~temp_converter() { delete m_impl; }

    float to_celcius() const    { return m_impl->to_celcius(); }
    float to_fahrenheit() const { return m_impl->to_fahrenheit(); }
    float to_kelvin() const     { return m_impl->to_kelvin(); }
    float to_reaumur() const    { return m_impl->to_reaumur(); }
    float to_rankine() const    { return m_impl->to_rankine(); }

    inline float as(units::celcius) const       { return to_celcius(); }
    inline float as(units::fahrenheit) const    { return to_fahrenheit(); }
    inline float as(units::kelvin) const        { return to_kelvin(); }
    inline float as(units::reaumur) const       { return to_reaumur(); }
    inline float as(units::rankine) const       { return to_rankine(); }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    temp_converter tc(-31, units::reaumur());

    std::cout << "Celcius: " << tc.to_celcius() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Fahrenheit: " << tc.to_fahrenheit() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Kelvin: " << tc.to_kelvin() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Réaumur: " << tc.to_reaumur() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rankine: " << tc.to_rankine() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know you only asked how to differentiate between units, but I got carried away while coding an example.

Comment: You might have gone a bit too far for someone who asks such a basic question :) Still, an interesting approach.

Comment: @ddriver Yeah I realize that. I've refactored it a bit locally because I actually like to keep this in my toolbox for later use.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this, you can specify the unit using an enum in the constructor parameter - a solution with a single constructor. In this case you will be passing a primitive number and the enum defines how its value is interpreted.

If you really need different constructors you can specify your own Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin types and pass those to different constructors.

```
struct Fahrenheit {
    Fahrenheit (double d = 0) : t(d) {}
    double t;
};

struct Celsius {
    Celsius(double d = 0) : t(d) {}
    double t;
};

struct Kelvin {
    Kelvin(double d = 0) : t(d) {}
    double t;
};

class Temperature {
public:
    Temperature(Fahrenheit f) {
        temperature.t = (f.t + 459.67) * 5 / 9;
        cout << "Fahrenheit constructor" << endl;
    }

    Temperature(Celsius c) {
        temperature.t = c.t + 273.15;
        cout << "Celsius constructor" << endl;
    }

    Temperature(Kelvin k) : temperature(k) {
        cout << "Kelvin constructor" << endl;
    }

    double getTemperature() {
        return temperature.t;
    }

private:
    Kelvin temperature;
};
```

And in main:

```
Temperature t1(Kelvin(50)), t2(Fahrenheit (90)), t3(Celsius(23));
cout << t1.getTemperature() << " " << t2.getTemperature() << " " << t3.getTemperature() << endl;
```

The output:

```
Kelvin constructor
Fahrenheit constructor
Celsius constructor
50 305.372 296.15
```

The class will store temperature internally as Kelvin (most scientific IMO) and will convert other units to Kelvin.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought of first, a single constructor solution. But I must use three, so thanks, the second solution seems OK.

Comment: @A6Tech - added a quick example to my answer

Comment: You should **definitely** mark all of the temperature structs constructor's as **explicit**!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - you are correct, but this is just a quick example. In general, all constructors that take only 1 parameter should be explicit in production code.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl BTW there is no room for an implicit conversion mistake here since passing a number to the `Temperature` constructor will result in ambiguous call anyway. It won't compile just as it would with explicit constructors.

Comment: @ddriver: true! Most probably at least two 'temperature structs' would be defined in the same namespace, so ambiguous match would be risen. Most probably I've developed a conditioned reflex for the sight of a ctor with single primitive type argument :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl my personal opinion is C++ is way too implicit, I'd rather have an `implicit` keyword for classes that I explicitly want to convert automatically and have all other constructors explicit by default.

Comment: Please tell me how can I write this another way:

Fahrenheit (double d = 0) : t(d) {}

without this colon.

Comment: You can remove the colon and move the `t(d)` in the body of the constructor, which is currently empty, or even use `t = d` instead.

Comment: Why doesn't this work:

`friend istream& operator>>(istream&in, Kelvin &k)
 {
  in>>k.t;
  return in;
 }`

Comment: No, I did it similarly, but I want to input the temperature instead of doing it in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I did it this way:

`double c; cin>>c; Temperature t1(Celsius(c));`